# ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property [###] on mx.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage

Tags: flash, apache-flex, blazeds

I get this intermittent error with BlazeDS / Flash when trying to send a message on a Producer.

```
 ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property remotePassword on mx.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage.
 ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property remoteUsername on mx.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage.
 ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property parameters on mx.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage.
```

The error doesnt appear all the time I can't find the behaviour that reproduces it - when it shows up the message is not received by the client.

Here's how I send it

```
     var rm:RemotingMessage = new RemotingMessage();
     rm.body = "some message";
    _producer = new Producer();
    _cs = new ChannelSet();
    _ch = new AMFChannel(config.AMF_ID, config.AMF_URL);
    _cs.addChannel(_ch);

    _producer.channelSet = _cs;
    _producer.destination = config.AMF_FEEDID;
    _producer.subtopic = config.SubTopic;
    _producer.addEventListener(MessageEvent.MESSAGE, processMessage);
    _producer.addEventListener(MessageFaultEvent.FAULT, processMessageFault);
    _producer.send(rm);
```

I can provide more info if needed - Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you specify RemotingMessage in imports?

Comment: In what IDE you develop?